# Vue triggering function with params from child unexpected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following component:

```
<template>
  <button class="button" @[click]="action">{{ text }}</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Button",
  props: {
    action: {
      type: Function,
      required: false
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    inputType: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    click() {
      return this.action ? "click" : null;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

However when I pass a function as the `action` with a parameter then the function is already triggered on render. Without a parameter it works fine.

```
<v-button inputType="button" :action="say('Hello')" text="Alert" />
<v-button inputType="button" :action="say" text="Alert" />
```

The triggered function:

```
say(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

You can see the behaviour [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/w20w72ywo7). Looking at [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) I would expect it to work with passing params.

So my question is how can I prevent the trigger on render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `$emit`

Instead of passing a function into the child component, you could instead emit a `clicked` event; e.g:

```
<button class="button" @click="$emit('clicked')">{{ text }}</button>
```

Then listen to the emitted event on the component itself, triggering your function:

```
<v-button inputType="button" @clicked="say('Hello')" text="Alert" />
```

Although emitting and handling events is a neat way to communicate  from a child component to its parent, it can break down somewhat when the component emitting the event is not a direct descendant; e.g: where the component is a grandchild.

Vue does not implicitly bubble events up through the component tree, I believe this is by design to ensure event behaviour is explicit.

#### Using `<slot>`

In this case, it's often desirable to use [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) to create a component that as access to the scope in which it was created, but then nest it within another child component.

```
<modal>
  <v-button @clicked="say('hi)" text="Alert"/>
</modal>
```

#### Using a higher-order function

Otherwise, if you need to pass a function to a child component, and that function also has an argument, you'll have to create it as a higher-order function.

In your case, you want to pass the `say` method to a child, with an argument. You want to pass the function but not invoke it, but when you pass an argument to `say()` you are invoking it there and then:

```
<v-btn :action="say('hi')">
```

The solution here is to rewrite `say` so it also returns a function, which will then be invoked when the button is clicked:

```
say (message) {
  return () => alert(message)
}
```

This implies that you *must* invoke the `say` method when passing it to the button component even if you are not passing a `message` to that button instance. So, the following will work:

```
<v-button :action="say()" text="Alert"/>
```

But this will not because it does not invoke the inner function:

```
<v-button :action="say" text="Alert"/>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have one problem with this solution. When for example a button is used in a dialog component I pass the function to the dialog and onto the button. This doesn't work while it did work before.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you are trying to pass a function to the button, which is actually a grandchild component because it's a child of a modal component? And of course (I understand by design) Vue custom events do not bubble up through multiple components.

Comment: If so, then one solution is to use `<slot>` to create child components in the parent scope and compose them within other child components—[example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4ylvy32m6). In this example we create a couple of `Button` components in the `App` component but then pass them into `Modal` component. The `Button` components can still invoke the `say()` method defined in `App` because of the scope in which they were created.

Comment: There are also [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) for when you want to do the opposite and ensure the slot content has access to the data of the component that they are slotted into.

Comment: I'll go for the `slot` solution. However I liked that I didn't have to provide the Button for each Dialog as they were already in the Dialog component it self. I would only have to define a action and text for the Button on the Dialog and they would appear.

Comment: Fair point. Slots are great for component composition and customisation but indeed, in some cases you may prefer to create components that are completely self-contained. Emitting events is generally considered idiomatic in Vue, so you could re-emit events—but I think this adds a bit of messy duplication.

Comment: Now—having said all that, you _can_ actually achieve what you were originally asking, by turning `say` into a higher order function. [Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k97pnq32jr). I didn't suggest this earlier as an emitted event seemed more like the "Vue way" to resolve your question.